# In what order do the Awesome Mix Vol 1 songs appear in Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, music, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

The Guardians of the Galaxy movie features several songs from Star-Lord’s Awesome Mix Vol 1 mixtape, compiled for him by his mother.

This mixtape (or [near enough](https://m.facebook.com/jgunn/posts/10152530342429570)) is available as one of the official soundtrack albums for the movie. However, the songs do not appear in the same order on the soundtrack as they do in the movie — the soundtrack opens with Blue Swede’s ‘Hooked on a Feeling’, whilst I remember that the first song we hear in the movie is 10cc’s ‘I’m Not in Love’ (when young Star-Lord is waiting in the hospital), followed by ‘Come and Get Your Love’ by Redbone (when adult Star-Lord explores the ruined temple thingy).

In what order do all the mixtape songs appear in the movie?

Comment: Since the movie spans a period of dozens of years, he may have rewound the tape a couple of times, causing the songs to be heard out of order.

Comment: @MrLister: oh yeah, the movie doesn’t show us the in-universe ordered track listing of the mixtape (or if it does, we can’t tell). But I’m just looking for the order in which we hear the songs whilst watching the movie.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Largely cribbed from [this site](http://www.what-song.com/Movies/Soundtrack/1465/Guardians-of-the-Galaxy).

1. I'm Not In Love - *10CC* (Track 6 on the soundtrack)

   > Young Peter Quill waits in the hospital corridor.
2. Come And Get Your Love - *Redbone* (Track 8 on the soundtrack)

   > Adult Peter Quill explores the ruined temple.
3. Go All The Way - *Raspberries* (Track 2 on the soundtrack)

   > Quill gets back to his ship with the orb.
4. Hooked On A Feeling - *Blue Swede* (Track 1 on the soundtrack)

   > Quill is tasered and hosed.
5. Escape (The Pina Colada Song) - *Rupert Holmes* (Track 10 on the soundtrack)

   > Quill flies from the prison to the ship.
6. Moonage Daydream - *David Bowie* (Track 4 on the soundtrack)

   > Quill’s ship arrives at Knowhere.
7. Fooled Around And Fell In Love - *Elvin Bishop* (Track 5 on the soundtrack)

   > Quill tells Gamora about a legendary earth hero.
8. Cherry Bomb - *The Runaways* (Track 9 on the soundtrack)

   > The team walk down a corridor, pre-mission.
9. O-O-H Child - *The Five Stairsteps* (Track 11 on the soundtrack) <sub>Note that the site lists this as song 11, but seems to be out of place.</sub>

   > Plays on the tape deck from Quill’s destroyed ship on the surface of Xandar.
10. Ain't No Mountain High Enough - *Marvin Gaye & Tammi Terrell* (Track 12 on the soundtrack)

    > First track on Awesome Mix Vol. 2, Quill’s mother’s dying gift to him.
11. I Want You Back - *Jackson 5* (Track 7 on the soundtrack)

    > A tiny regenerating Groot dances, while Drax polishes his sword.
12. Spirit in the Sky - *Norman Greenbaum* (Track 3 on the soundtrack)

    Used in the second trailer, but does not play in the actual movie.

Comment: Actually, OOH Child does play, albeit briefly, shortly before the moment you mentioned in the spoiler tag.

Comment: @raumkrieger it does indeed, the tape deck starts playing it.

Comment: Ha! I started doing that same exact edit a while back, @PaulD.Waite and then quit for some reason. I forget why.

Comment: Also note that, while *Ain't No Mountain High Enough* is explicitly shown on-screen as being on Volume #2 of the mix tape; it's not clear which volume contains *I Want You Back* given the timing of it's appearance.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: very true, we have no confirmation on this yet. We’re really drilling down into the important details here guys.

Comment: @phantom42: well, [I have previous](http://www.pauldwaite.me.uk/smallpaul/badbreaks/) for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

1. I'm not in love
2. Come and get your love
3. Go all the way
4. Hooked on a feeling
5. Escape
6. Moonage Daydream
7. Fooled around and fell in love
8. Cherry bomb
9. O-o-h child
10. Ain't no mountain high enough
11. I want you back

Comment: While not wrong, this does nothing to add any information not already posted in other answers.

Comment: Slightly neater format, for those of us in the TLDR crowd.

Answer (score 2):

Spirit in the Sky does not appear in the movie whatsoever. It only plays in one of the trailers for Guardians of the Galaxy.

https://www.marvel.com/articles/movies/get-the-full-tracklist-for-marvel-s-guardians-of-the-galaxy-soundtrack

Comment: Correct. And what about the order of the rest of the songs?

Comment: Very true, although we’ve got that covered in phantom42’s answer. (It was in a spoiler tag, but I’ve removed that having realised it’s not a spoiler.)

Comment: Perfectly wonderful song! The decision not to include was likely made pretty far up.