# In what order are the Awesome Mix Vol 2 songs heard in Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, music, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

The Awesome Mix for [*Guardians of the Galaxy Volume 2*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3896198/?ref_=nv_sr_7) has been [released](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XW4SNMD).  Awesome Mix Vol 1 had all the songs from the mixtape we see in the movie, but we hear them in a different order in the movie than they are arranged on the soundtrack.

We know the movie order for Volume 1 because of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67932/in-what-order-do-the-awesome-mix-vol-1-songs-appear-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy).  Is the movie order of the songs for Volume 2 different than soundtrack order, and if so what is the movie order?

[image: Image of the trackless for the soundtrack.]

Comment: Pft. Like the movie, this question is way too derivative of the original.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the **Guardians of the Galaxy: Awesome Mix Vol. 2** track list in movie order:

1. ***Brandy*** (Meredith and Ego's scene)
2. ***Mr. Blue Sky*** (Intro with dancing Baby Groot)
3. ***Lake Shore Drive*** (Milano flying out of the Sovereign's planet)
4. ***The Chain*** (Star-Lord and friends travel to Ego's planet)
5. ***Southern Nights*** (Rocket vs. the Ravagers)
6. ***My Sweet Lord*** (Ego's planet)
7. ***Come A Little Bit Closer*** (Yondu's awesome scene)
8. ***Bring It On Home To Me*** (Peter & Gamora dancing)
9. ***Brandy*** (Played again on Ego's planet)
10. ***Wham Bam Shang-A-Lang*** (Sovereign attack; listened to by Kraglin)
11. ***The Chain*** (Star-Lord's power-up scene)
12. ***Father and Son*** (Star-Lord and Baby Groot listening to Zune)
13. ***Surrender*** (End credits)
14. ***Flashlight*** (End credits)
15. ***Guardians Inferno*** (End credits)

Trailer:

- ***Fox on the Run*** (not played in the movie)

To refresh your memory, I made a playlist of those songs in that order. Feel free to check it out: https://open.spotify.com/user/alvinrodz/playlist/7oxnrKwpWrAPNq5PDfbSnh

Comment: Who do you mean by Milano?

Comment: @LimboExile: *the Milano* is the ship that the Guardians travel in.

Answer (score 3):

I am trying to remember the whole order, but this is about as close as I can get. The Question marks are not exact, but close to the right order. The numbered are absolute certainties.

This one comes first as it was in is in the trailers but *not* in the movie:

1. *Fox on the Run* by The Sweet

Here on out, the rest are in the movie:

2. *Brandy (You’re a Fine Girl)* by Looking Glass
3. *Mr. Blue Sky* by Electric Light Orchestra

These I am not 100% sure on:

4. *The Chain* by Fleetwood mac
5. *Lake Shore Drive* by Aliotta Haynes Jeremiah
6. *Bring it on Home to Me* by Sam Cooke
7. *Southern Nights* by Glen Campbell
8. *My Sweet Lord* by George Harrison
9. *Come a Little Bit Closer* by Jay and the Americans

Pretty sure of the order on these:

10. *Wham Bam Shang-a-Lang* by Silver
11. *Father and Son* by Cat Stevens
12. *Surrender* by Cheap Trick
13. *Flash Light* by Parliament
14. *Guardians Inferno* by Guardians Inferno

Answer (score 1):

- Brandy (You’re a Fine Girl)
- Mr. Blue Sky
- Lake Shore Drive
- The Chain
- Southern Nights
- My Sweet Lord
- Come a Little Bit Closer
- Bring It on Home to Me
- Brandy (You’re a Fine Girl)
- Wham Bam Shang-A-Lang
- The Chain
- Father and Son
- Surrender
- Flashlight
- Guardians Inferno