# What other MCU films have ended with existing pop songs over the credits?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, music

*Iron Man* ended with the Black Sabbath song of the same name, and now *Captain Marvel* ended with "Celebrity Skin" over the credits. I can't recall off-hand if any other of the films have used already-known songs the start of the credit roll, as opposed to new music as part of the score.

Answer (score 14):

They sure have!

- *Iron Man 2*, unlike most other MCU movies, doesn't have a fancy animated credit sequence, but AC/DC’s “Highway to Hell” plays over its last scene and continues into the credits.
- *Guardians of the Galaxy* also doesn't have a fancy animated credit sequence*, but “I Want You Back” by the Jackson 5 plays over the “The Guardians of the Galaxy will return” screen and the pre-credits scene, where newborn Groot appears to dance to it.
- *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* does the same with “Surrender“ by Cheap Trick (although it continues over the credits), and later we hear both “Flash Light” by Parliament, and “Guardians Inferno” (featuring cast member David Hasselhoff).
- The animated credits for *Spider-Man: Homecoming* feature “Blitzkrieg Bop” by The Ramones.
- Black Panther's animated credits have “All the Stars” by Kendrick Lamar and SZA. It's from the soundtrack, but it was released as a single about six weeks before the movie came out.
- *Spider-Man: Far From Home* has “Vacation” by The Go-Go's over its animated credits. (For the record, we also hear “A Message to You, Rudy” by The Specials playing in the background of its post-credits scene).
- *Eternals* ends with “Feels Like the First Time” by Foreigner (feels like [the *last* time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternals_(film)#Future) more like)
- *Spider-Man: No Way Home* has “The Magic Number” by De La Soul over its animated credits
- *Thor: Love and Thunder* has "Sweet Child of Mine" by Guns N' Roses over its animated credits, as well as "Rainbow in the Dark" by Dio over the first part of its black-and-white credits.

<sub>* *Guardians* does have “I'm Not in Love” by 10cc over its opening flashback, and has a title card and credits early on in the movie, backed by “Come and Get Your Love” by Redbone. *Guardians 2* follows a similar pattern with “Brandy (You're a Fine Girl)” by Looking Glass and “Mr Blue Sky“ by ELO respectively. In a sort-of similar fashion, *Spider-Man: Far From Home* opens with “I Will Always Love You“ by Whitney Houston.</sub>

Comment: You were right GotG 1 has "I Want You Back" cut off when the credits roll.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: when it comes to music in *Guardians of the Galaxy*, [I certainly should know](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67932/in-what-order-do-the-awesome-mix-vol-1-songs-appear-in-guardians-of-the-galaxy?rq=1).

Comment: Didn't Iron Man 3 also end with a pop song too?

Comment: @CBredlow: it certainly _starts_ with one (_Blue_ by Eiffel 65), but I think they went with a score for the animated credits.

Comment: @CBredlow: specifically “Can You Dig It (Iron Man 3 Main Titles)” from the soundtrack album.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite not that's it the actual question but I'm also fairly sure GotG2 started with Mr Blue Sky by ELO...

Comment: @JonClements It shows up pretty early in the movie, sure, but the very start has *Brandy (You're a Fine Girl)* by Looking Glass throughout the flashback to 1980.

Comment: Captain America: Civil War has the song "Left Hand Free" performed by Alt-J playing over the closing credits.  The song also appears in the scene that introduces Peter Parker.

Comment: @NathanK.: it does, although it starts in the middle of the credits, after some of the score.

Comment: Isn't there a Foo Fighters or Linkin' Park song over the credits of the first Avengers film?

Comment: @Darren: Yes! Well-remembered — Wikipedia informs me that it was [‘Live to Rise’ by Soundgarden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_(soundtrack)#Track_listing_2), although not over the fancy animated credits. It's terrifying to think how much perfunctory grunge dross we could have been subjected to without James Gunn.

Comment: Edited to contain information on Thor: Love and Thunder

Comment: @PeterNielsen thank you! I couldn’t remember whether the animated credits were one of the few parts of the movie _without_ Guns ‘n’ Roses playing.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It's definitely hard to remember, but I had the misfortune of having to see it twice...